# I have a very bizarre malware that I cannot seem to get rid of

Tags: malware, virus, rootkits, firmware, audio

Here is my horror story that I thought I would share to see if one had any great suggestions and maybe would be interested in researching my problem because it is very fascinating. If you are interested in looking at my problem I am happy to do a share screen. If you do discover the exploits this malware uses you would probably make 40k in bug bounties alone on top of my 1k.

Edit:This might seem implausible and but I would happily introduce you to my friends who were also infected if you need be if you do not believe me.

Description:
I have a very bizarre malware that I get on any computer if I play a song from an infected computer or I open up my email or even sign into my email. Wiping the drive does nothing. I have gone to the genius bar, geek squad and they could not help and I have spent thousands trying to fix this.

I have installed different operating systems Ubuntu, Windows and OS X on different systems and the malware remained. I think what I have is rootkit that turns into a boot kit as soon as I make a significant change in the OS such as upgrading to a different version. On one protective PC desktop (probably the best one), after I got the malware again I tried the factory rest on the PC. What was bizarre is after the computer restarted the computer said “A request has been made to change keys to the firmware” at the boot up screen with white letters and a blue background. I selected “no” between the two choices of yes or no. This was the only time of all the many computers I have tested that after the factory reset, the computer did not still have the symptoms of the malware after the reset. Typically the sound quality, visual quality and speed become worse after a reset with the malware actually.

I have gone through various computers and even infected friends computers on accident, so this has become a very heart breaking problem.

To test whether it really exists and that I am not just making it up is I tested the two main infection methods on the computers at Best Buy. As soon as I either played a music file I made from an infected system on a clean system things became different on the clean system. The computers became a little slower, the sound of the computer both became warped and sharp sounding. You could say distorted. If you logged into an email that I used on an infected computer the same thing generally happened, but to a lesser extent. I did learn I have a rootkit called Linux/Ebury on my main computer, but I can’t prove if it is related for sure. The other bizarre thing is the sound quality and volume of the computer then changes throughout the week and it seems nearly like a timed cycle. I cannot watch movies or anything on infected computers because the sound becomes so bad.

It sounds like this thing was created in a lab because the only similar malware I have heard of is Bad USB and a couple others that seems to be able to infect any system. I personally believe the malware gains access to my firmware on the motherboard and changes keys related to the sound through out the day. I call it a “sound cycle.” The volume changes significantly and the quality changes slightly throughout the week. If for instance when I have apple completely wipe and reinstall my mac, what is interesting and telling is the Macbook stays in the “sound state” it was right before I wiped it. The sound cycle seems to stop and the “sound state” becomes static. However as soon as I either play a song or movie created from the old system or log into my email, the cycle continues again. I have tested this 5 times to make sure.

I could go on about my research and my struggles, but I really just don’t know what to do to fix this problem other than maybe completely getting a different identity with new email accounts and what not and tossing my old computers. However that would be incredibly expensive and if I slip up and have the malware come back it would all be for nothing. I need to figure out a way to a 100% prevent it.

Comment: Could you specify a clear question?

Comment: Sure, can you help me get rid of this issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this does not provide enough information to figure out what's really going on. The questions consists of a few observations mixed with strange explanations. But probably lots of information are missing and the reported observations might be warped but the explanations the OP already has. Also, if the OP really has spend thousands already and is willing to spend more than why not simply burn the infected system and buy a new one?

Comment: To me it sounds like there are no actual symptoms that would be best explained by a virus.

Answer (score 4):

Your observations aren't plausible from a technical perspective.

Your malware spreads via audio files. Malware can't be arbitrarily "attached" to a file. Rather, a malicious sound file would work by triggering an unpatched vulnerability in a sound driver / media player program.

Your malware infects different operating systems on different machines. It's implausible that any malware would be able to exploit audio software on all these systems at once... and then attract attention by distorting your sound.

There could be [electromagnetic interference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_interference) at play or simply a malfuction of the sound card or speaker.

Comment: I have done research of situations where code has been activated into a working picture or audio file. http://picateshackz.com/2015/02/how-to-make-virus-and-hide-in-image.html The technique to do this in an audio file is very similar, although is very rare.

Comment: The other thing like I said that is happening is the rootkit, Linux/Ebury was found on my current system and I tested for false positives and the rootkit does exist. But aside from that this malware likely came from pirated Music Software, similarly to how BMI had a rootkit for sharing their music files, I think this is similar from a Music company.

Comment: I am well aware of the implausibility or else this would be much easier to figure out. I shouldn't say it is the exact same if I install a different OS. But the sound state that it was before I installed the system is stuck in that sound state till I either play a music file or log into my email.

Comment: When I got the malware 3 years ago the electromagnetic interference was my first guess actually. I tried many different techniques to try to stop it and with no success. I also have traveled to 4 states, had roughly 14 computers and all have seem to have gotten infected eventually. I wish I could show you the sound quality on all 4 of my current computers. I would be happy to send you an audio file and you can see if I am lying. :)

Comment: @Eric Feel free to upload the audio file somewhere and link it. Nobody is suggesting you're lying, just that you're drawing the wrong conclusions.

Comment: Certainly, please be very careful     video file, audio file and email account login   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6_D_xNWiNQfdlA0UHBKbzhxMEk/view?usp=sharing https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6_D_xNWiNQfbFoxOHpwN1RxY00/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It typically take around an hour to start seeing the malware take place, try playing a normal audio file from your computer and try downloading and playing one of mine and maybe try just logging into the email account if you are brave. Typically the first stage is the computer audio will be little crappier in audio quality than before you played one of my files. The next stage is if you make a copy of one of my files the next stage of change might happen.

Comment: The one way guaranteed to make the audio quality of the computer is use and DAW or audacity, put the file in there and export twice. That has worked every time.

Comment: Eric - providing your account and password **will** get your machine compromised. The rest... Sorry, not plausible.

Comment: Upload the sample to Virustotal (or similar) and provide a link.